# Dash doesn't show figure created with px.imshow

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

As in the title, Dash doesn't display a figure (picture) created with px.imshow. Below is my code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go # or plotly.express as px
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],
                    [[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0]]
                   ], dtype=np.uint8)
fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
])
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I used this [documentation page](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/). At the very bottom, it says:

> Everywhere in this page that you see fig.show(), you can display the same figure in a Dash application by passing it to the figure argument of the Graph component from the built-in dash_core_components package like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go # or plotly.express as px
fig = go.Figure() # or any Plotly Express function e.g. px.bar(...)
# fig.add_trace( ... )
# fig.update_layout( ... )

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)  # Turn off reloader if inside Jupyter
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run your code and pass `fig` to the dash `app` object, the figure renders normally for me. Have you upgraded to the latest versions of plotly and dash? Are you in a jupyter notebook by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the version's fault. This time I was installing packages via conda, I thought it was also downloading the latest version just like pip.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I changed to make it run is:

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
```

instead of

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
```